# Google Sheets - Apps to send keystrokes

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to copy paste cell data from Google sheets to another program?

I have data on google sheets.

I need the script to copy data in cell A2 to another program. With Excel macro, we use AppActivate.
Then I need to send an "Enter" keystroke, then copy B2 to the program.

Then put in date / timestamp in C2. Before progressing down the rows to the last row.

Is this possible with Google Sheets App Script?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. Thank you for responding.

So Column A2 has "William"
I wanted the app to copy "William" to our work software
Paste it in, then send [Enter].
Then goes back to the Google sheet.
Goes to B2 which has "Smith". Copies this, then goes back to the software and paste it in then send another [Enter] keystroke. Waits for 10 seconds, send another [Enter] keystroke.

Then goes back to the sheet, and in Cell C2, put the current timestamp in (so I know when it has been entered.

Then it goes on to the next row (A3, B3 until the last row - could be 90, could be 120)

Comment: Thank you for replying. First, Google Apps Script is run with the server side (Google side). About `to our work software` of `the app to copy "William" to our work software Paste it in`, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand `software`. But, `software` is on your local PC? If my understanding is correct, I think that your goal cannot be directly achieved by Google Apps Script. For example, if your `software` can be run by giving values with a script on a local PC, I think that your goal can be achieved. But, I have no information about your `software`. I apologize for this.

Comment: Ah. No problems. Thanks for trying :) It's actually our company's own internal program that's not available outside of the organisation. I was hoping there was a shortcut rather than keying in things. Slowly :( Thanks again @Tanaike. Your input was very much appreciated.